Dark clouds on gas giants
One of the gas giants in my star system has large areas of its atmosphere filled with cloud layers that are pitch black when looking at them from space.
What material could those clouds be made of to achieve such effect? And what mechanism could lead to formation of such dark areas?
When searching around I found that compounds such as Iron(II,III) Oxide and Manganese Dioxide are black and would form black clouds when suspended in the giants atmosphere as particles. I don't know how realistic it is to have such compounds in such vast quantities in a gas giants atmosphere though. Then again I'm willing to hand wave things a bit for the sake of  cool planet design so I don't need 100% realistic explanation, just looking for some other interesting compounds / materials that could create such dark cloud fields.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudarsky%27s_gas_giant_classification

Gaseous Carbon
If you're looking for a traditional gas giant like Jupiter, I don't know of chemistry that will do what you're looking for, but if you're willing to embrace an exotic gas giant idea, you could look at carbon. To kickstart this, let's look at the blackest of the black:

Substances which absorb almost all the light falling on them appear black. Therefore you are looking for the blackest known compound. The record is currently held by Vantablack, a substance composed of vertically aligned carbon nanotubes, which absorbs up to 99.965% of visible light incident upon it. ...it is really black. (Chemistry.SE)

Carbon nanotubes don't occur naturally — but carbon does! It's one of the most abundant materials in the universe. With an atomic weight lighter than Oxygen, it's reasonable to believe that carbon can be gaseous and, therefore, produce very dark (ain't gonna be black) regions on your planet.
The problem is that carbon is sticky (strong chemical covalent bonds), meaning it sticks together with itself and almost everything else. That's one of the reasons why it's the basis for terrestrial life. On your gas giant, you need carbon to NOT stick to itself or anything else. Can that be done?
Yes, you can heat Carbon to about 3,600℃, at which point it turns into a gas. So your gas giant must be hot! And to give you an idea of how hot it is, the surface of the sun is about 5,600℃. Which means your gas giant must be of a size and nature to be a sub-brown dwarf or something getting close to it. It needs a hot enough core to keep the carbon gaseous, but not so hot as to set the whole thing blazing.
I do not know if we have found evidence of gaseous carbon in a solar or planetary body. Nor do I know if, insofar as we understand science today, it's deemed possible to have an exotic gas giant like this. What I do know is that this would be a really cool planetary body.

The whole gaseous carbon thing seems super neat and making the gas giant into a sub brown dwarf would also be amazing (its already the biggest planet in the system) but I think at 3600 C* the surface would be glowing kinda defeating the point, right? Anyways I may just handwave that part and make the carbon stick into larger particulates that can stay non reactive at lower temperatures or something like that. Thanks for sharing!

@Juno Parts of it might. You won't have hydrogen because it will have burned away in that heat. You'll have heavier elements and they might be glowing in the visible spectrum. It'll all be glowing in the thermal (infrared) spectrum. Are you looking for something that sits there and can't be seen at any level of electromagnetic radiation or reflection? There's nothing that will do that.

Im fine with the planet glowing in infrared, its just that turning the temperature up to 3600* will make the whole planet glow in visible light I think and I dont want that - I want the planet to have a particular cloud color scheme and one of the colors is black. I guess thats what happens when you design the planet first and then think about scientitic explanations for why things look the way they do - you can run into a situation where theres no realistic explanation for your design.

@Juno Not necessarily, it would depend on what elements are in the atmosphere. You won't have hydrogen or helium as the heat would have boiled them off. You'll have heavier elements. And, yes, it's always possible for your imagination to be fantastic rather than realistic. That's not actually a bad thing unless you're writing a documentary or a textbook. We've learned things about space in the last ten years we would have laughed at as pure fantasy thirty years ago. Check out Clarke's third quote.

There are carbon stars. There are even stars that produce so much carbon that they hide themselves completely. But carbon stars are giant stars, not something the size of Jupiter.
Soot hangs in the Earth's atmosphere for about a week. You would need some reaction that continuously produced it in the upper atmosphere.

I can't find emissivity numbers for diatomic gaseous carbon, but if it's anything like CO2, it should be glowing at 3600C, right? Emissivity for gasses was always confusing to me.

Vantablack is no longer the record holder as of 2019. MIT came out with a 10x improvement: https://news.mit.edu/2019/blackest-black-material-cnt-0913

@SRM That's cool! And it completely rationalizes undetectable high orbit alien spy satellites!

@DanielB This question isn't tagged [tag:science-based] or [tag:hard-science]. It might be, but the point here is to rationalize a goal.

Yeah I'm mainly looking for unusual compounds & reactions that would produce those compounds, to explain the colors of the atmospheres of my gas giants, they don't need to be super realistic or probable (the planets already have quite exotic colors) - I just love explaining various features of planets in my system with weird materials and reactions.

3900K is white hot, not black. I don't know if carbon vapor would glow a noticeably different color from its blackbody color (a bright yellowish white like sunlight at sunset).  At 3900K, I doubt it would be detectable without a spectroscope.

The absence of science-based tag really shouldn't be an invitation to rationalize the goal by giving advice that will achieve something diametrically opposite the goal.

@gs That's a judgement for the OP to make, not you. If the Stack has a "default" scope, it's [tag:science-fiction], not [tag:science-based]. All I did was offer a perspective for a solution. If the OP doesn't like it, that's OK and the OP's choice... not yours. If you think my answer is so bad that it deserves a down vote, then by all means... but maybe you should offer an answer of your own, first. Personally, I don't know if carbon glows at the stated temperature. I only know that it becomes a gas, which is needed to answer the question.

I have downvoted this answer, then.

Carbon (and everything else, so: the whole planet) does glow at that temperature. In this case "glow" is a poor choice of words: the planet will shine about 20% as brightly as the sun per solid angle. If you're interested in reading more, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation
